# In how many ways can three balls can be drawn from the box if at least one black ball is to be included in the draw? Why this solution is wrong?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Question is :- A box contains $2$ white balls, $3$ black balls and $4$ red balls.  In how many ways can three balls can be drawn from the box if at least one black ball is to be included in the draw?

My Solution :-

Since at least $1$ black has to be included so we can select $1$ black ball out of $3$ in $3C1$ ways

Now for the rest two balls it can be of any colour, so $2$ balls can be selected out of $8$ balls in $8C2$ ways

So final solution is $3C1 \cdot 8C2$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: By designating a black ball as the black ball that must be included, you are counting each selection with more than one black ball multiple times, once for each way you could designate one of the black balls as the black ball in the collection.

Comment: There are $9C3$ total ways. How many don't have *any* blacks?